# Makefile, how to have prerequisites given by function with target as argument

Tags: makefile

I have a list of files contained in another file. I want to use this list as prerequisite for some target and for doing so I use a function that reads the list from file.

The problem is that I have different lists for different targets so I need to pass the target as argument to the function that reads the list. Something like that (that does not work):

```
getlist = $(shell cat $1)

tmp%: $(call getlist, %)
    @cat file1 >  $@
    @cat file2 >> $@

file%:
    @touch $@
    @echo "$@" > $@

clean:
    @rm file1 file2 tmp
```

where the list for building the `tmp1` file is in the `1` file, the one for building the `tmp2` file is in the `2` file and so on and so forth.

If I have instead `tmp1: $(call figlist, 1)` all works, but I need something capable of treating different file names.

If needed for the solution I can also change the way I named the files.

Comment: How many of these files are there, and what is their format?

Comment: @Beta there are about 10 files with lists (simply one path per row) which contains 5-10 path each

Comment: This solves the problem: `.SECONEXPANSION: tmp%: $$(call getlist, %)` but I don't know if it is the best solution

Comment: It is probably the best for your purposes. There are alternatives. Since the number of files is small, you could read them all outside the rules and keep the prerequisite lists as variables. This would mean unnecessary reading, but the makefile would be simpler.